# Code returns empty string if variable is 0

Tags: php

Whenever Capacity is 0 - my PHP code seems to return only the phrase **Showing** instead of **rooms with a capacity of 0**. How can I resolve this?

```
$allowedFields = array(
    'Capacity',
    'Location',
    'RoomType'
);
// Retrieve only the allowed fields
$fields = array_intersect_key($_POST, array_flip($allowedFields));
// Remove whitespace
$fields = array_map('trim', $fields);
// Remove empty values
$fields = array_filter($fields);
// Filter values for HTML output
$fields = array_map('htmlentities', $fields);
// Create the variables
extract($fields, EXTR_SKIP);
{
$heading = 'Showing';
if(isset($RoomType)) {
    $heading .= ' ' . $RoomType;
}
if(isset($Capacity)) {
    $heading .= sprintf(' rooms with a capacity of %s', $Capacity);
}
if(isset($Location)) {
    $heading .= sprintf(' in %s Park', $Location);
}
}
```

Comment: Do a `var_dump($Capacity)` and `var_dump($_POST)`. I wonder if a capacity of 0 is getting lost as a null in `array_flip()`, and consequently not getting extracted...

Comment: `isset($Capacity)` is returning false. You haven't shown the code where you assign `$Capacity`.

Comment: Sorry I forgot to say that it is accepting 0 as entry from the user

Answer (score 4, accepted):

array_filter might be removing the value since it's zero.

from php.net

> if no callback is supplied, all entries of input equal to FALSE (see converting to boolean) will be removed.

Answer (score 2):

`array_filter` is the problem. Without a callback, it removes all array entries that are falsey. See here: http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-filter.php

Comment: What if it the user typing in 0 on a form?

Comment: Regardless of the entry method used, if the value is zero, the current code will strip it out.

Answer (score 1):

array_filter remove 0 values... remove the array_filter statement